# kubectl proxy open a page with tons of 404s

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm setting it up on azure.

I've created this script based on what I managed to find in the Azure documentation:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$( dirname "$0" )"

source vars.sh

echo "Create group $KUBE_GROUP"
az group create \
    --verbose \
    --name $KUBE_GROUP \
    --location $LOCATION

echo "Create acs $KUBE_NAME"
az acs create \
    --verbose \
    --name $KUBE_NAME \
    --resource-group $KUBE_GROUP \
    --orchestrator-type Kubernetes \
    --dns-prefix $KUBE_NAME \
    --generate-ssh-key \
    --agent-count 3 > creategroup.log 2>&1

echo "Get credentials for $KUBE_GROUP"
az acs kubernetes get-credentials \
    --verbose \
    --resource-group $KUBE_GROUP \
    --name $KUBE_NAME > getcredentials.log 2>&1

echo "Create registry $REGISTRY_NAME"
az acr create \
    --name $REGISTRY_NAME \
    --resource-group $KUBE_GROUP \
    --location $LOCATION \
    --admin-enabled true \
    --sku Basic > create_registry.log

echo "Setup kubernetes environment"
ssh-keygen -f "${HOME}/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "${KUBE_NAME}mgmt.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com"
scp azureuser@${KUBE_NAME}mgmt.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:.kube/config $HOME/.kube/config

kubectl config current-context

#echo "Create a single nginx instance in kubernetes"
#kubectl run namenginx1 --image=nginx

REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$( az acr credential show \
    --name $REGISTRY_NAME \
    --resource-group $KUBE_GROUP \
    | jq '.passwords[0] .value' \
    | sed 's/"//g' )

echo "Create secret docker-registry"
kubectl create secret docker-registry kuberegistry \
    --docker-server $REGISTRY_URL \
    --docker-username $REGISTRY_NAME \
    --docker-password $REGISTRY_PASSWORD \
    --docker-email $REGISTRY_EMAIL > kuberegistry.log 2>&1

nohup kubectl proxy &
firefox 'http://localhost:8001/ui/'
```

Now, I'd expect to see the kubernetes dashboard where I can do a lot of things. But it seems this is not the case. If I open the FF console, I see tons of 404s and the page remains blank.

Does anybody see the reason why it's not working? Or give me any suggestions on how to solve the issue?

Thanks

---

I've tried to execute `az acs kubernetes browse -g $KUBE_GROUP -n $KUBE_NAME` but I'm getting this error:

```
'proxycommand'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/main.py", line 36, in main
    cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/application.py", line 212, in execute
    result = expanded_arg.func(params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 377, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 620, in _execute_command
    reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 602, in _execute_command
    result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 154, in k8s_browse
    _k8s_browse_internal(name, acs_info, disable_browser, ssh_key_file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 164, in _k8s_browse_internal
    _k8s_get_credentials_internal(name, acs_info, browse_path, ssh_key_file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py", line 835, in _k8s_get_credentials_internal
    '.kube/config', path_candidate, key_filename=ssh_key_file)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.0.19/libexec/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/acs_client.py", line 65, in secure_copy
    proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand(host_config['proxycommand'])
KeyError: 'proxycommand'
```

NOTE: I've made sure that the `kubectl proxy` was not running and that the port was not 'busy'.

Comment: are you sure its 8001? can you do kubectl browse?

Comment: I'm sure about port 8001. The `kubectl browse` gives a tells `Error: unknown command "browse" for "kubectl"`

Comment: @Stefano Do you try `az acs kubernetes browse -g $KUBE_GROUP -n $KUBE_NAME`. I test your script, if I use this command, I could open Web UI. If possible, you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your script in my lab, there is a mistake in your script.

`{KUBE_NAME}mgmt.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` it should be `{KUBE_NAME}.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`. No need mgmt.

If you want to connect to the web UI, you need running

```
az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=$KUBE_GROUP --name=$KUBE_NAME    
nohup az acs kubernetes browse -g $KUBE_GROUP -n $KUBE_NAME &
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-ui).

Update:

You need check `.kube/config` file, if possible, you could recreate it.

The issue is because browser cache. Clean up the cache in the browser will solve this issue.

---

External Update:

Beside the cache, when the command opens the page on your browser, it'll go directly to `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy`. There's a missing / in the end. It should be `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/`

Comment: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname stekubespecial.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` but `stekubespecialmgmt.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com` works. The other command returns a `'proxycommand'` command followed by a bunch of  stack trace I'll edit in the question itself.

Comment: It is very strange, I use your script, k8s DNS name does not have mgmt, do you check it on Azure Portal?  You could use `az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=$KUBE_GROUP --name=$KUBE_NAME` to download certificate and execute `az acs kubernetes browse -g $KUBE_GROUP -n $KUBE_NAME`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, in your script you have add `az acs kubernetes get-credentials --resource-group=$KUBE_GROUP --name=$KUBE_NAME`. Do  you check you have get right `.kube/config` file?

Comment: Inspecting the .kube/config solved the issue: there were stale caches still in there. The config itself worked since I can add/update pods and deployments. Anyway I deleted the content of the whole folder and regenerated the config. Still the address and the command you suggested don't work.

Comment: @Stefano `Still the address and the command don't work.` What do you mean?

Comment: By address, I was referring the mgmt (noticed now that you removed it) and by command I mean the one in your answer which returns only stacktrace and do nothing. I'm still using the `kubectl proxy` without the caches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158147/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-stefano).